# I want to add Multiple records to database which are dynamically generated based on certain selections in cakephp2.6.1

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to generate semester rows dynamically based on selections and inputs and store all of them at the same.

````
<pre>
public function saveData() {
        $this->autoRender = false; // Disable view rendering

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $data = $this->request->data;

            // Assuming you have a model called Data in your application
            $this->loadModel('ETest');

            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $this->ETest->create();
                $entity = array(
                    'cycle' => $row['cycle'],
                    'course' => $row['course'],
                    'year' => $row['year'],
                    'semester' => $row['semester']
                );
                $this->ETest->save($entity);
            }

            $response = array('message' => 'Data saved successfully.');
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
</pre>```


This is my controller method.
````

Comment: And what's not working about this?

Comment: you could use $this->ETest->saveMany($this->request->data) or you could add $this->ETest->clear(); after save()
additionally I would recommend adding 'fieldList' => ['cycle', 'course', 'year', 'semester'] for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
$this->ETest->saveMany($this->request->data)
```

or you could add

```
$this->ETest->clear();
```

after calling ->save() I would recommend adding

```
'fieldList' => ['cycle', 'course', 'year', 'semester']
```

for security reasons